# Android repeating daily alarm not repeating correctly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I have an alarm that I am wanting to repeat around every day.

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long cuurent=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

but not call BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Does `AlarmService` extends `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 1):

Your `PendingIntent` is calling `getBroadcast`, but it looks like your intent is a Service.  If that is true, change your PendingIntent to instead call `getService` like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```